# Flash AS3: Blitting performance at 1080p/4k resolution?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, blit

When I started my Flash project, I didn't know anything about blitting. I intended for it to play at 60 FPS, but it frequently dips into the 40s on a high-end machine and worse on lower-end machines. All of the game artwork is vector because I liked how it's perfectly scalable, for cases where you want to zoom in, or if the user is playing full screen on a high resolution display.

Then I learned about blitting and did some experimenting with positive results. But before I write a blitting engine, I was wondering what kind of performance I could expect. My Flash is set to 60 FPS and I'm going to use an `EVENT.ENTER_FRAME` to call my blit function, which would then go through each of my background, midground, and foreground vector art `Sprite` layers and create bitmaps by using `BitmapData.drawWithQuality` before `copypixel`ing them onto my canvas bitmap. I plan on scaling my vector layers and canvas bitmap resolution up to the user's full screen resolution, which could be something huge like 4k. Those could be some huge bitmaps with huge draws occurring at a high rate. Can I really expect to get 60 FPS if I go through all this effort?

Comment: Most of the benefits of blitting comes from only redrawing portions of the screen each frame and not having to redraw everything. If you are blitting the background and other large areas I cant imagine that you would get much benefit. It completely depends on what you are trying to do though. Have you looked into using multiple sets of pixel assets (low res / high res) to retain your good visuals but save flash the processing on rendering new bitmaps every frame. Without more context this would be my best guess. Good Luck!

Comment: You should just try using bitmaps instead of vector before you get into complicated blitting. In general, bitmaps use the gpu and aren't redrawn and vectors use the cpu and are redrawn every frame. You can create everything in vector and convert movieclips to bitmaps (tile bitmaps larger than the screen dimensions) so that there are no vectors, only clips of bitmaps. This all happens during "loading." Then you simply show or hide and move bitmaps around on the screen during "playing." I can show you example convert-movieclip-to-bitmap code if you want.

Comment: I'm hesitant to go with bitmaps because they will have to be large in order to look good when scaled up, and they would bloat up the file size I'm sure since I have many frames of animation. They seem to be the way to go though for performance, but fortunately my game doesn't have tons of stuff flying around, so I am going to try and optimize things with vectors. Thanks for the offer though.

Comment: There is no scaling bitmaps with this method. You scale the vectors. You resize the vectors to whatever size needed to match the display. Then create a bitmap copy of the vector image, remove the vector, and use the bitmap. For example, you draw a 200x100 vector gradient for the background, when the app loads resize that background to match the display, create a bitmap copy of the background, remove the vector background, and add the bitmap. You get a fullscreen pixel-perfect bitmap from a 200x100 vector.